# How do I pass a variadic macro to a function?

Tags: clojure

I am attempting to learn Clojure and am having trouble with macros. I have a simple macro:

```clj
(defmacro add [& x] `(apply + (list ~@x)))
```

and then I have a function that can call multiple operations (add, subtract, multiply, and divide). I get these from stdin but for simplicity I have created a variable holding a list of numbers:

```
(defn do-op
  [op]
  (def numbers (list 1 2 3))
  (apply op numbers))
```

In order to call `do-op` with the appropriate operation I need to pass the macro to `do-op` in an anonymous function:

```
(do-op #(add %&))
```

When I run this code using arguments passed from stdin I get a confusing error:

```
Cannot cast clojure.lang.ChunkedCons to java.lang.Number
```

When I execute this in a REPL I get:

```
Cannot cast clojure.lang.PersistentList to java.lang.Number
```

I assume that this has something to do with my lack of understanding of how these variadic arguments are getting handled but I am thoroughly stumped. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never ever pass a macro as if it was a function, since it doesn't exist after the code is compiled and ready to run.

When you have;

```
(do-op #(add %&))                              ; which is shorthand for
(do-op (fn [& rest] (add rest)))               ; then you expand the macro
(do-op (fn [& rest] (apply + (list (UNQUOTE-SPLICE 'rest))))   ; how do you unsplice the symbol rest to be separate elements?
```

The short answer is that `rest` can never be unspliced and thus you are using the macro wrong. However it seems you are just making an alias for `+` and it can be done by making a function or just making a binding to the original:

```
(defn add [& args] (apply + args)) ; making a function that calls + with its arguments
(def add +)                        ; or just make a binding pointing to the same function as + points to
(do-op add) ; ==> 6
```

You should keep to using functions as abstraction. Whenever you need to write something very verbose, where you cannot make it a function because of too early evaluation, then you have a candidate for a macro. It then translates a shorter way to write it with the long verbose way to write it without knowing the actual data types behind the variable symbols, since the compiler won't know what they are when expanding the macro. Also a macro gets expanded once, while the function that had the macro might get executed many times.

**EDIT**

In your pastebin code I can confirm you never ever need a macro:

```
(cond
  (= 1 option) (do-op #(add %&))
  ...)
```

Should just be

```
(cond
  (= 1 option) (do-op +)
  ...)
```

No need to wrap or make macro for this. Pass the function as is and it will do what you want.

Comment: This is really good to know. I struggled to understand when to use a macro vs. a function so I really appreciate that clarification. I know that implementing an `add` is completely unnecessary but was just using it as an exercise to learn Clojure syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @carpenter, the thing to realize is that macros provide a way to abstract "syntax".  Therefore, macros should be reserved for situations where there is a truly compelling reason to introduce new syntax.  Unfortunately, this isn't as easy or straight-forward as it sounds ;-).  But experience can help, so keep playing with them!

Answer (score 0):

Macros run at compile time and transform code data, not runtime data.

There is simply no way to generically apply to a macro a form evaluating to a sequence (like the symbol `numbers`) because it needs be to evaluated first, which can only happen at runtime (after compile time).

This is the full answer. Hopefully it helps you along understanding macros in Clojure.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you are thinking, you should do it more like this:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require 
    [tupelo.core :as t] 
  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn add [& x] 
  (apply + x))

(def numbers [1 2 3] )

(defn do-op
  [op]
  (apply op numbers))

(spyx (do-op add))

(defn do-op-2
  [op vals]
  (apply op vals))

(spyx (do-op-2 add numbers))
```

to get result:

```
> lein run
(do-op add) => 6
(do-op-2 add numbers) => 6
```

Usually we try to avoid having functions access global values like `numbers`.  With `do-op-2` we pass the vector of numbers into the function instead.

Note:  For `(spyx ...)` to work you're project.clj must include

```
:dependencies [
  [tupelo "0.9.9"]
```

### Update

Of course, you don't really need `do-op`, you could do:

```
(defn add-all [nums-vec] 
  (apply + nums-vec))
(spyx (add-all numbers))

;=> (add-all numbers) => 6
```